# Set up Facebook pixel to fire on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, onclick

I want to set up a pixel to fire when a button is clicked. Facebook offers [some info here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration#in-page-events) on doing this very thing, but I am a javascript novice and can't figure it out. How does one use the info on that page to alter the code below to fire on a button click? Here is the base code snippet:

```
<script>(function() {
var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
if (!_fbq.loaded) {
var fbds = document.createElement('script');
fbds.async = true;
fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
_fbq.loaded = true;
}
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'MyPixelID', {'value':'0.01','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just missing the function to call which "fires" the pixel and the button...

Javascript:

```
function myButtonClicked(val, curr) {
  //Do your thing
  window._fbq.push(['track', 'MyPixelID', {'value':val,'currency':curr}]);
}
```

And the button:

```
<button onClick="myButtonClicked(val, curr);" />
```

Or a link styled to look like a button:

```
<a href="javascript:myButtonClicked(val, curr);">Text</a>
```

And, continuing on per the comments:

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="myButtonClicked(val, curr);">Text</a>
```

*Note: In the line above, the `onclick` is processed first, then since propagation is not cancelled by any means, the `href` navigation executes.*

Comment: Okay I've got the first part. Don't fully get the button part though. If I have a button in the HTML that looks like this: `<a class="mybutton" href="http://#.com">Click Me</a>` how does `<button onClick="myButtonClicked(val, curr);" />` fit into that?

Comment: Well, the anchor tag `a` is for links and `button` is for buttons, so your question changes a bit.  I'll edit above.

Comment: Great thanks! So how do I still send the clicker to a certain URL if the href is taken by `javascript:myButtonClicked(val, curr);`?

Comment: lol... the many-parts question?  This is it for me on this one.  Editing now.

Comment: You're a saint. I'm like an old lady that needs help crossing the street.

Comment: If we push ourselves forward, we will all find ourselves in that spot.  Glad to be of help.  Since we've got it, be sure to click the checkmark to show the question was answered. And, welcome to SO!

Comment: Thx! SO is an intimidating place. Still learning how to ask Q's without getting downvoted and told it belongs in a different SE community, and then ultimately deleting it. Again, you're a saint.

Comment: Happens to me almost always when I ask a question.  I just delete the question and keep researching and hoping the few I ask will find an answer. Gotta keep trying. :)

Comment: @JeremyMiller I know this is old, but maybe jorwesflow needs to comment the last two lines of the </script> section if he wants to fire the event of conversion ONLY when a button is clicked.